# How to Receive UDP Concurrent Request?

Tags: c#, java, c, sockets, udp

I'm building a UDP server that handles each incoming request in a separate 
thread. The problem is, a UDP client may send out multiple requests 
concurrently by using multiple threads. Each thread on the client will wait 
for responses from the server. Since UDP is connectionless, a client thread 
may receive a mismatching datagram. In this case, does have any 
built-in mechanism or pattern that helps a client thread to get the matching response? 
(for example send each request from server to specific udp port !!?)
I don't want use queue because it lost concurrently property.
If not, I guess we can build a queue that dispatches responses to 
appropriate client threads. However, what if I need to run multiple clients 
in different JVMs on the same client machine, and each client will make 
requests to the same server?

Comment: By the way, the queue concept is totally out of place here. There is no network queue that can identify which client you want to talk to. If you meant message queues they are used for IPC (inter process communication) between processes on the same machine. Working remotely sockets is the way.

Answer (score 2):

Use a separate socket for each udp client. That way you have a different ip and port for sending and would receive response on the same i.e. the client which sent the request would only receive it's response (i presume that is what you meant by matching) This should be done automatically unless you share the same socket between threads and use it to send messages to server which seems like a bad idea.

You can set any port in your source (sender port) in client before sending message to server. The server can extract your source port and respond to the same port

e.g.

```
Client 1 source port:10401 -> server:listening port:2000.  Server responds to port 10401. 

Client 2 source port:10402 -> server: listening port: 2000. Server responds to port 10402.
```

Comment: The Problem is that i send Multiple request from one ip address.and i can only use udp connection and udp port is 53 then i cant use multiple port from out side. For example i use download manager For downloading and download manager use 10 separate thread for receive request concurrently . how can i manage this ?

Comment: Are you saying you can't use any port other than 53 for even sending? Generally in a client we never set a sender port and it is automatically chosen by the stack for us i.e. some random port like 4543. This is an unusual requirement i.e. only a fixed client port. Or were you talking about server port?

Comment: I have not problem from server side .server sent my response from an other computer in internet. can i sent request from server to specific client local port for example 127.0.0.1:9865 . and i can use only udp port then i think that i can use only port 53 for send and receive my request  . is it true ?

Comment: You can set any port in your source (sender port) in client before sending message to server. The server can extract your source port and respond to the same port e.g. client 1 source port:10401 -> server:listening port:2000. Server responds to port 10401. Client 2 source port:10402 -> server: listening port: 2000. Server responds to port 10402.

Comment: first thank you for response But I know 127.0.0.1 is local host my Purpose is that if i send request from my local host for example 127.0.0.1 :8090 with orginal valid ip 37.65.31.25 to an other computer in internet that is my server .server get my request and it want response me. can server able to sent request with udp to my local host port 8090 that i sent request ?

Comment: send request from client local host 127.0.0.1 :8090  =====> the orginal client valid ip is 37.50.12.36 
server receive request from client and responce to 37.50.12.36
server send responce to 37.50.12.36 :53 (the valid client internet ip)
i want to know that can server able to send responce to local port 8090 ???

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand what bothers you. I think a few of your concepts are not clear. First if client is using 8090 as source port, generally it means it would also be listening on this port for a response. The server is listening for incoming requests on port 53. But it does not respond on 53. It responds to 8090. Rather you can code in any port number that you wish to send server's response to. The point is server knows which port client used as its sending port so it responds to the same one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to do concurrent connections, make multiple connections. Spawn a new UDP connection on the client, the server will just open a new connection on it's end. Anything sent on connection1 on the client comes in on comes on on connection1 on the server, anything sent on connection2 gets received on connection 2.

Comment: I think that because udp is connectionless protocol and each connection sniff one port i cant use this solution.

Comment: Incorrect, you can still track the port of the client, which will be a random high value number. each thread talks to it's own IP+Port combo. See [fayyazki's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644417/how-to-receive-udp-concurrent-request/12644830#comment17055018_12644546)

Comment: are you say that i can sent request from server in other country to specific client local port ?for example sent to 127.0.0.1 : 6069

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is not another country. It is local host i.e. sending message to your local same machine. And you can send message to another computer on the local port which that client used to send message to you. Take a look in wireshark or other tool at any tcp/ip packet. It contains both source and destination ports. Where source port is the port that other computer used to send message to you and you respond to it on that port only, not just any other port.

Comment: first thank you for response But I know 127.0.0.1 is local host my Purpose is that if i send request from my local host for example 127.0.0.1 :8090 with orginal valid ip 37.65.31.25 to an other computer in internet that is my server .server get my request and it want response me. can server able to sent request with udp to my local host port 8090 that i sent request ?

Comment: send request from client local host 127.0.0.1 :8090  =====> the orginal client valid ip is 37.50.12.36 
server receive request from client and responce to 37.50.12.36
server send responce to 37.50.12.36 :53 (the valid client internet ip)
i want to know that can server able to send responce to local port 8090 ???